# Disclosing agent for showering?

Tags: hygiene, alzheimers

Dentist have disclosing tablets that are chewed to teach/give feedback on the effectiveness of tooth brushing.  Is there a disclosing agent, that for example, can be sprayed on before showing? This might be handy for alzheimers patents.

Comment: This could also be helpful for someone who is caring for a patient who is unable to bathe themselves.